# google page does not appear in my Electron application

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I am using eletron framework to make desktop application and i need to show google search page in it.
When i try to show normal html page in my project, it appears with no problem. But when i try to use online website it does not appear. I need to know if i did something wrong, i have just followed a tutorial

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')


function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(`https://google.com`)
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') 
     app.quit()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "loadURL" instead of "loadFile", [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) you find more information